# users and posts database issue

Tags: php, mysql

Is it true that after a user signs up, a sql table is create for him to store his posts ?
I make it similar in mysql after the man insert him into my page. The database is the same name with but the table name is made when he log in first time.

```
class Users
{
    var $username="root";
    var $password="pass";
    var $database="InsertIntoStackOverflow";
    var $table_name="";
    public function Users($username)
    {
       $table_name=$username."_tb";
       echo $table_name."<br/>";
       mysql_connect(localhost,$username, $password) or die("unable to connect to database ".mysql_error());
       echo $database."<br/>";
       mysql_selectdb($database) or die("unable to select db ".mysql_error());
       $query="CREATE TABLE ".$table_name." (id tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, date_post VARCHAR(100), date_edit VARCHAR(100), post_content TEXT NOT NULL)";
       mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to create table. ".mysql_error());        
    }
}
```

But it display only table_name and an error, the database name not display. Error is NO DATABASE IS SELECTED/

EDIT

This class is call after he sign up 
I also have a function postApost but when I do

```
ob_start();
session_start();
require("Users_DB.php");
$name=$_SESSION['user'];
echo 'Welcome '.$name;
$username=new UserDB($name);
```

there is no table created

Comment: Ohh..... what is `UserDB` actually? i see your class name is `Users`.

Comment: Oh really I forget to edit it before posting. too nice of you.

Comment: Why in the world do you think you need a new table for every user to store posts in? You only need *one* table, with a `user` field to store the related username, and then `INSERT` all posts into that one table.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, it is great if you explain details and easy steps I am newbe, I not have a idea to process your idea. I think one user has 100 posts, another has 100 posts then should be 2 users and 200 differing posts

Comment: I first learned about building database-driven PHP "apps" from an [old O'Reilly book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005436.do). [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Build-Database-Driven-Website-Using/dp/0957921802) might be a good place to start. What you're doing is data modeling, so you might read up (here's a [tutorial](http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_data_modelling/index.htm) that might help).

Comment: And to answer your edit, no, don't do that.

Comment: @user1058271 - Here is another answer that I gave that tries to explain some of the thinking behind object-based data modeling (with tables on the backend storing the data): http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6965/designing-a-multi-restaurant-schema/6966#6966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two variables with same name `$username`. Use `$this` for accessing variable of class. Missing quote(") with `localhost` - it must be string type parameter. and this code can't create table on Database because you use `AUTO_INCREMENT` on your code but forgot to mention that as a `PRIMARY KEY`. I think the following code help you a lot.

```
class Users
{
    var $username="root";
    var $password="pass";
    var $database="InsertIntoStackOverflow";
    var $table_name="";

    function __construct($user_name)
    {
       $this->table_name=$user_name."_tb";
       echo $this->table_name."<br/>";
       mysql_connect("localhost",$this->username, $this->password) or die("unable to connect to database ".mysql_error());
       echo $this->database."<br/>";
       mysql_selectdb($this->database) or die("unable to select db ".mysql_error());
       $query="CREATE TABLE ".$this->table_name." (id tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, date_post VARCHAR(100), date_edit VARCHAR(100), post_content TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))";
       mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to create table. ".mysql_error());        
    }
}
```

And you can use this class by the following way :

```
$clsName = new Users('username');
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it depend on version of php pople work with. your version is no new. it fine without qode in my php.

Comment: Do you know how I can pass a string to that constructor ?

Comment: What do you want to do actually? Explain first.

Answer (score 1):

Create *one* table:

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
    id TINYINT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    date_post DATETIME,
    date_edit DATETIME,
    post_content TEXT NOT NULL
)
```

Inserting new posts:

```
$insert = "
INSERT INTO Posts (
    user,
    title,
    date_post,
    date_edit,
    post_content
) VALUES (
    '$username',
    '$title',
    NOW(),
    NOW(),
    '$post_content'
)
";
```

Updating is simple:

```
$update = "
UPDATE Posts SET
    title = '$title',
    post_content = '$post_content',
    date_edit = NOW()
WHERE id = '$postid';
";
```

Get all posts for user:

```
$posts = "
SELECT title, date_post, date_edit, post_content
FROM Posts
WHERE user = '$username'
ORDER BY date_post
";
```